RDP periodically stops working on Ubuntu 22.04
I have setup Remote Desktop successfully on ubuntu 22.04 and have been able to login from a Windows 10 PC using the native RDP client. However, after a day or so, I received a 'fail to connect'. After checking that my firewall settings and IP address were still the same, I finally tried turning the Remote Desktop toggle off and on again on the ubuntu machine. This fixed it, and I was able to login with RDP from the windows machine again. Unfortunately this is not a sufficient fix, as it requires physical access to the machine. Does anyone know what causes it to stop working and how to prevent that? It almost seems like a hidden timeout setting that keeps the visual toggle 'on'.

@john, I haven't installed XRDP or anything through the command line, I only used the desktop gui.

And I have not logged out since it was setup, so that is probably not the cause.

I have exactly the same problem on fresh Ubuntu 22.04
